# How to convert JSON to array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, regex

How to format below javascript variable into an array

**Current Format**

```
[
 { "REQUEST_ID": "ABC123", "STATUS": "PRINTING", "TYPE": "AUDIT", "DESCRIPTION": "SAMPLE", "COPIES": "10"},
 { "REQUEST_ID": "CDE123", "STATUS": "AUDIT", "TYPE": "APPROVED", "DESCRIPTION": "ORDER", "COPIES": "1" }
]
```

**Required Format**

```
['ABC123', 'PRINTING', 'AUDIT', 'SAMPLE', '10'], ['CDE123', 'AUDIT', 'APPROVED', 'ORDER', '1']
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterate the array with [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) as the map's callback:

```js
const data = [{"REQUEST_ID":"ABC123","STATUS":"PRINTING","TYPE":"AUDIT","DESCRIPTION":"SAMPLE","COPIES":"10"},{"REQUEST_ID":"CDE123","STATUS":"AUDIT","TYPE":"APPROVED","DESCRIPTION":"ORDER","COPIES":"1"}];

const result = data.map(Object.values);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You win in terms of saving bytes. ;)

Comment: It giving error as `Line: 15
Error: Array.prototype.map: argument is not a Function object` in IE EDGE. Is there something else is required for IE

Comment: it works fine with my edge.

Comment: @RAM - Object.values us supported by Edge 14+. It's not supported by IE.

Comment: Okay..I am using IE 11 ..What can be the possible solution for this version?

Comment: You can use a [polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es7-object-polyfill) or use for...in (see [Adam Azad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52237285/5157454)), or Object.keys with map (see [Nina's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52237316/5157454)).

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = [
 { "REQUEST_ID": "ABC123", "STATUS": "PRINTING", "TYPE": "AUDIT", "DESCRIPTION": "SAMPLE", "COPIES": "10"},
 { "REQUEST_ID": "CDE123", "STATUS": "AUDIT", "TYPE": "APPROVED", "DESCRIPTION": "ORDER", "COPIES": "1" }
]

arr.map( x => Object.values(x))
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array.map` and then `Object.values` (see [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=object-values)) to get an array of the object values.

```js
var r = [
 { "REQUEST_ID": "ABC123", "STATUS": "PRINTING", "TYPE": "AUDIT", "DESCRIPTION": "SAMPLE", "COPIES": "10"},
 { "REQUEST_ID": "CDE123", "STATUS": "AUDIT", "TYPE": "APPROVED", "DESCRIPTION": "ORDER", "COPIES": "1" }
].map(o => Object.values(o));

console.log(r)
```

IE does not support `Object.values`. So, you might consider a polyfill or use a `for` loop.

```js
var r = [
 { "REQUEST_ID": "ABC123", "STATUS": "PRINTING", "TYPE": "AUDIT", "DESCRIPTION": "SAMPLE", "COPIES": "10"},
 { "REQUEST_ID": "CDE123", "STATUS": "AUDIT", "TYPE": "APPROVED", "DESCRIPTION": "ORDER", "COPIES": "1" }
].map(function(o) {
    
   var a = [];
   for(k in o) {
      a.push(o[k]);
   }
   return a;

});

console.log(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside the given answers which rely on the order of the object, you could use an array with the keys for the wanted order of the items.

```js
var array = [{ REQUEST_ID: "ABC123", STATUS: "PRINTING", TYPE: "AUDIT", DESCRIPTION: "SAMPLE", COPIES: "10" }, { REQUEST_ID: "CDE123", STATUS: "AUDIT", TYPE: "APPROVED", DESCRIPTION: "ORDER", COPIES: "1" }],
    keys = ['REQUEST_ID', 'STATUS', 'TYPE', 'DESCRIPTION', 'COPIES'],
    values = array.map(o => keys.map(k => o[k]));

console.log(values);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```